# Insert bulleted text in Powerpoint using Open XML C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml, openxml-sdk, office-automation

I am creating one slide PowerPoint file using open XML. I have tagged the placeholder in the PPT which i need to update programatically. I am able to find the placeholder and can update its value from the database.

Now the problem is I need to display some text in bullets.

Here is my Code.

```
    var presPart = myPres.PresentationPart;
        var slideIdList = presPart.Presentation.SlideIdList;

        var list = slideIdList.ChildElements
                    .Cast<SlideId>()
                    .Select(x => presPart.GetPartById(x.RelationshipId))
                    .Cast<SlidePart>();


        var tableSlidePart = (SlidePart)list.First();
        var secondSlidePart = (SlidePart)list.Last();
        var current = tableSlidePart;
```

> Below line is working fine when i need to paste simple plane text

```
        List<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Text> textList = tableSlidePart.Slide.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Text>().Where(t => t.Text.Equals("IntroText")).ToList();
        foreach (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Text text in textList)
        {
            text.Text = "Some Text";
        }
```

> How can i display some text as a bullet points in a placeholder?

Any help or pointer would be appreciated. Thank you in advance